# How can I get MySQL to store the result of a query from a second table in the first one?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of business centers. Sometimes the data entry people don't have all the information such as a missing city name, but the rest of the information is complete. I have another table of zipcodes. I want to be able to do a zipcode lookup for those addresses which don't have a city, and get the city name. I'm doing this in MySQL.

I'm having difficulty with getting the MySQL for this right. I don't know if it's a syntax issue or the logic of the MySQL is wrong. This is what I have:

```
update centers city
set centers.city = (
select zipcode_types.primary_city
from centers, zipcode_types 
where centers.city="" and centers.zipcode=zip);
```

This is the error I'm getting from the above MySQL:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'city' for update in FROM clause
```

What I'm attempting to do, is find the city name from the zipcode_types table and update the 
missing city name in the centers table. I appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: you are missing a '.' between centers and city on your first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multi-table [update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

```
update centers 
  inner join zipcode_types on zipcode_types.zip = centers.zipcode
set centers.city = zipcode_types.primary_city
where centers.city='';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your update statement as follows:

```
update centers set city=(select zipcode_types.primary_city from zipcode_types where enters.zipcode=zipcode_types.zip)
where centers.city=''
```

as show on this SQL Fiddle page: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f7b5/1

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
UPDATE centers SET city = (
SELECT primary_city
FROM zipcode_types 
WHERE zipcode=city.zip) 
WHERE city IS null 
OR city ==''';
```